# How to make wide format dataframe to long format in R?

Tags: r, long-format-data

I am trying to make a box plot out of a dataframe with 1000 rows and 80 columns.
It currently looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K23KK.png)

Now I want to move each column to stack 80 different columns but not sure how to do that.
How can I separate the columns and stack to make a wide format dataframe to a long format data?

Current dataframe looks like this:

```
age1 age 2 age3 
x1   y1    z1 
x2   y2    z2 
x3   y3    z3
```

Desired outcome is:

```
age value
 1   x1
 1   x2
 1   x3
 1   x1
 2   y1
 2   y2
 2   y3
 3   z1
 3   z2
 3   z3
```

Comment: Try with `stack()`. Can't help you more given you do not provide a code example nor a detail of your expected output.

Comment: See [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dataframe like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  age1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  age2 = c(4, 5, 6),
  age3 = c(7, 8, 9)
)
```

You can use 'pivot_longer' to get your desired outcome:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("age"),
               names_to = "age",
               names_prefix = "age",
               values_to = "value") %>% 
  arrange(age)
```